# Chained REPLACE functions substitute only one value at one query execution

Tags: mysql, sql, replace, sql-scripts

In the tuples under Album_IDs 1 and 8 I want to replace the 'Genre' field values of 'Alternative' with emptiness (''). But when I'm executing this SQL-script, it replaces only one value at once. Is there a way to leave the half of the string (namely, 'Indie' genre, apart from 'Alternative' and the commas and spaces surrounding it) and execute the script so that all values were replaced at a heat? And what is wrong with my code?

```
UPDATE Album
SET Genre = REPLACE(REPLACE(Genre, ', Alternative', ''), 'Alternative, ', '')
WHERE Album_ID < 9
```

[image]

Comment: Fix your data model so you are not storing lists in a string column!

Comment: Get rid of your Likes

Comment: @DanielMarcus, Yeah, I've forgotten I kind of uploaded the wrong version of the script. 1 sec

Comment: Looks good - whats the problem with what you have now? What exactly are you getting and what are your expected results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following using [`TRIM`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_trim) and [`REPLACE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_replace):

```
UPDATE Album
SET Genre = TRIM(TRIM(BOTH ',' FROM TRIM(REPLACE(Genre, 'Alternative', ''))))
WHERE Album_ID < 9
```

> **demo:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3c6fe1/1/0

Comment: Thanks, but in the eighth record the comma before 'Indie' has left.

Comment: It requires two executions to remove it. Is it correct?

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly. By the way, can you tell me, what was wrong in my script?

Comment: Your query looks good, but doesn't replace only `Alternative`.